# Using Split() without parameters, what is the default delimiter?

Tags: c#

So I looked at the `String.Split()` method in C# today and I realized that you can pass it zero arguments as well which I never considered.

What is the default delimiter when you use `Split()` without any parameters?

Comment: That would be "White space"

Comment: What is wrong with [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? Did they take it offline?

Comment: FYI: If you press F1 from Visual Studio you are taken to the MSDN page on the Type Member/Method you are on.

Comment: I didn't really consider clicking the one version of the method that described the use of `params`. I just looked at the overall description of the `String.Split()` method :)

Comment: I think that is available in google.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case of no values it's white space - source from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the separator argument is null or contains no characters, the
>   method treats white-space characters as the delimiters. White-space
>   characters are defined by the Unicode standard; they return true if
>   they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

Comment: Oh, thanks! That looked pretty puzzling to me when I stumbled over it in some production code today :)

Comment: [Quite a number of characters!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,1151), you can see that if you're passing `null` or an empty array (default for a `params` parameter if you omit the argument), it's using [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if the string contains whitespace characters and adds them to the list of separators.

ProTip! Next time you're wondering what a framework method does, check out the source at [sourceof.net](http://sourceof.net).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1):

The default is whitespace - but to add upon the other answers, this *includes* `\n` newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the MSDN page for String class should explain which chars are default separators if they are omitted. We can also further inspect the source code on Reference Source for the string class here :

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,10c5b3e0ef2b8a70,references

The method * MakeSeparatorList* contains the logic for building up an array of separator indices using Char.IsWhiteSpace  as can be seen. So combine both the docs on MSDN and also ReferenceSource to inspect the source code itself if you want to really check the details. But the documentation with remark on MSDN should suffice for most developers of course. It is though interesting sometimes to delve into the source code of .NET.