# Splitting strings in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

Let's assume in my console the user inputs a couple or few strings separated by spaces.

I'm using these lines of code to organize the inputs into an array:

```
string[] inputs = Console.ReadLine().Split();
string firstName = inputs[0];
string lastName = inputs[1];
```

My goal by posting this is to better understand the `Console.ReadLine().Split();` command. Microsoft documentation is a bit lost on me. Does this command read inputs and enable them to be separated by empty spaces? I'm assuming that is the case because in the code snippet we are declaring index 0 to be the string variable firstName and index 1 to be the string variable lastName.

I have also seen this command used as `Console.ReadLine().Split(" ");`. What kind of different functionality does this offer?

Edit: For duplicate notification: This question concerns the mechanics of this command and how it gets placed into an array specifically. Thanks for your responses. The 'duplicate' is a bit more general and did not succeed in answering my question.

Comment: Does this make it clearer? `string line = Console.ReadLine(); string[] tokens = line.Split();`. [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) without parameters uses all [white-space characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) as delimiter(like space, tab, new-line).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Split() without parameters, what is the default delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977503/using-split-without-parameters-what-is-the-default-delimiter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two different "operations": `Console.ReadLine()` and `String.Split()`, first returns `string` from user input, second splits it. It will be equivalent to:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] result = input.Split();
```

You can call as many methods (properties, fields, etc) as you want after dot operator, but it will be better, if you make your code readable (well, in this example it is pretty simple).

If there is no parameter passed, it will be whitespace by default, from MSDN:

> If the separator argument is null or contains no characters, the method treats white-space characters as the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard; they return true if they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

References: **[Console.Readline()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)**, **[String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)**, **[. Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operator)**

Answer (score 0):

Read the input from the console

```
var inputs = Console.ReadLine();
```

Split the input string by whitespace

```
var splitInputs = inputs.Split(' ');
```

Check if the split array has at least one element and take its values

```
string firstName = splitInputs.Count()>0 ? splitInputs[0] : string.Empty;
```

Check if the split array has at least two elements and take its values

```
 string lastName = splitInputs.Count() > 1 ? splitInputs[1] : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Code only answers are not a good fit for this site, can you add an explanation to show why this is the answer?

Comment: @Equalsk- just added the quick explanation. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can just use `Split()` and not pass any parameters if you're going to be using whitespace as that is the default.

Comment: thats true- Split() works without passing any parameters. It treats default as whitespace.